# Python2.7: Extract slice from a list based on a pattern in a Pythonic way

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, list-comprehension

I have a large set of data in a list. The list consists of short strings. Inside the list are slices of length 5 hidden that match a certain pattern:

```
[<date>, <date>, <4 digit integer>, <string>, <$ amount>]
```

How can I extract these slices from my data set? They can occur in any location (so their index is not guaranteed to be a multiple of 5) and are interspersed with other data (also strings), that can match part of the pattern.

I started with something similar to:

```
for item in data:
    if re.search(<date pattern>, item):
        if not date1:
            date1 = item
        else:
            date2 = item
    if re.search(<4 digit integer pattern>, item):
        if date1 and date2 and not fourdigit:
            fourdigit = item
        else:
           date1 = None
           date2 = None
    ....
```

But this is very complicated, prone to errors and not pythonic at all.

The next approach was to extract a sliding window of 5 items from the list of data and check that all items match their pattern. If not, increment the index by 1 (i.e. slide the window by 1) and check the next slice. If the pattern matches, save the slice, and increment the index by 5. Something like:

```
index = 0
while index < (len(data)-5):
    sliceof5 = data[index:index+5]
    if slice_matches_pattern(sliceof5):
        matching_items.append(sliceof5)
        index += 5
    else:
        index += 1
```

This works and is a lot easier to implement and less error prone previous solution, but doesn't seem very pythonic either.

Is it maybe possible to do this using list comprehension? Something like:

```
matching_items = [ sliceof5 if slice_matches_pattern(sliceof5) for sliceof5 in data ]
```

But then, how do I make the `for` in the list comprehension sometimes skip forward 1 and sometimes forward 5.

Are there maybe other, pythonic ways to achieve this?

Comment: My first instinct is to use `re` to reliably match on each string, and a list comprehension or loop to apply it to all strings in the list.  Another option is to join all strings into one big string (or blocks of strings) and use a more comprehensive `re` matcher (multiline?)

Comment: Your second suggestion I get (especially after seeing the answer of @double_j). Your first suggestion I don't get, especially the list comprehension part. There can be, for instance, 3 dates in a row of which only the last two can be part of the overall pattern I am looking for. And how do you match the sequence of 5 patterns? You somehow have to 'remember' the items you pulled out of the list during list comprehension.

Answer (score 2):

Your second solution seems fine. I would change it to a generator (`yield` the slices you find), but not more.

You can probably make it run faster, though, by looking for a date in item number 2 of the slice. If it's not a date, you can add two to the index.

Of course, if you can turn everything into one big regular expression that matches your entire pattern, you'll do even better.

Answer (score 2):

Having no idea what your data looks like, following @hpaulj's idea, here's a regex approach.

```
import re

data = [
    '2016-12-01', '2016-12-02', '1234', 'spam', '$100',  # collect
    '2016-12-02', 'spam',  # discard
    '2016-12-01', '2016-12-02', '1234', 'spam', '$100',  # collect
    '1234', '2016-12-01',  # discard
    '2016-12-01', '2016-12-02', '1234', 'spam', '$100',  # collect
    '$100', '1234', '1234',  # discard
    '2016-12-01', '2016-12-02', '1234', 'spam', '$100'  # collect
]

pattern_sep_str = '||'  # change to something unique in the data

pattern_sep = re.escape(pattern_sep_str)
date_pattern = r'[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}'
int_pattern = r'[0-9]{4}'
str_pattern = r'[a-zA-Z]+'
amount_pattern = r'\$[0-9,.]+'

pattern_combined = ''.join([
    '(', date_pattern, pattern_sep, date_pattern, pattern_sep,
    int_pattern, pattern_sep, str_pattern, pattern_sep,
    amount_pattern, ')'
])

results = re.findall(pattern_combined, pattern_sep_str.join(data))

print([x.split(pattern_sep_str) for x in results])

>>> [['2016-12-01', '2016-12-02', '1234', 'spam', '$100'], ['2016-12-01', '2016-12-02', '1234', 'spam', '$100'], ['2016-12-01', '2016-12-02', '1234', 'spam', '$100'], ['2016-12-01', '2016-12-02', '1234', 'spam', '$100']]
```